# Retrieve "same as parent folder" A record using Get-DnsServerResourceRecord

Tags: domain-name-system, powershell

I am trying to retrieve a single A Record from a zone. Here's the Powershell command I am using(showing only relevant columns)

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -zonename search.contoso.com -computername g-dc03 -RRType A

HostName                  RecordType RecordData
--------                  ---------- ----------
@                         A          192.23.12.40
stg                       A          172.25.77.56
```

In the "DNS Manager" GUI, I see the first record as "same as parent folder". I would like to retrieve just this one record, not the stg record. I tried and failed with the following commands, all of them result in same 2 rows.

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -zonename search.contoso.com -computername g-dc03 -RRType A -Name "."
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -zonename search.contoso.com -computername g-dc03 -RRType A -Name '.'

Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -zonename search.contoso.com -computername g-dc03 -RRType A -Name search.contoso.com

HostName                  RecordType RecordData
--------                  ---------- ----------
search.contoso.com        A          192.23.12.40
stg                       A          172.25.77.56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName search.contoso.com -computername w-dc03 -RRType A | ? {$_.Hostname -like '@'}
```

You can replace `@` with any search term, or you can change the `-like '@'` to `-notlike 'stg'` to list all A records other then the `stg` record

If that isn't what you are looking for please post a comment and I will amend accordingly

EDIT: Doing the same without `where`

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName search.contoso.com -computername w-dc03 -RRType A >> output.txt

Select-String -Path .\output.txt -Pattern "(@|HostName)" |select line
```

Comment: Do you know a way of getting it without using Where? With parameter -Name maybe?

Comment: @Afr added another way, not using -Name but this does work. You could take this further and use `$variables` for the file name, and bring in input files etc if you need to do a lot of zones

Comment: I am sorry this isn't what I want. From cmdlet authoring standpoint, every result should be uniquely identifiable. One doesn't have to resort to filtering the resultset to get the unique value. My question: is there a way to just use Get-DnsServerResourceRecord to get a unique value without having to filter the resultset? Get-DnsServerResourceRecord does seem to take -Name parameter but I am unable to get the row I want by just using -Name parameter.

Comment: @Afr try using Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -zonename search.contoso.com -computername w-dc03 -RRType A -Node TechNet example suggests that will work

Comment: Can you please update your answer with -Node? This is exactly what i was looking for.